# Caused by: org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

This code executing Hibernate queries runs ok as Java program, but if I run it as Spring Boot it fails
I've read somewhere it might be because of bugs in Hibernate 5.1. Might it be?
I'm using Spring Boot 2.0.  Would it be an issue?

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringCd244ManyToManyBootApplication {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringCd244ManyToManyBootApplication.class, args);

    // create session factory
            SessionFactory factory = new Configuration()
                                    .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                                    .addAnnotatedClass(Instructor.class)
                                    .addAnnotatedClass(InstructorDetail.class)
                                    .addAnnotatedClass(Course.class)
                                    .addAnnotatedClass(Review.class)
                                    .addAnnotatedClass(Student.class)
                                    .buildSessionFactory();

            // create session
            Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
            try {....
```

Error that I get when run it in Spring Boot. Any ideas?

```
2018-01-11 20:45:33.261  INFO 5772 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling    : HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/webapp?useSSL=false]
Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private io.scalando.Instructor io.scalando.Course.instructor] by reflection for persistent property [io.scalando.Course#instructor] : Course [id=0, title=Pacman - How To Score One Million Points]
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getPropertyValue(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:626)
```

Comment: try to add the mapping classes of Course and Instructor

Comment: Don't understand what you mean. Like in this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20680859/add-mapping-classes-as-a-separate-xml-file-in-hibernate

Comment: Somebody reported this issue, I am posting the link for your reference.
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7906

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar issue that was fixed by removing this dependency:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
<optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Yep, thats worked for me too. Using SpringBoot 2.0.4.RELEASE incl. Hibernate 5.2.17

Comment: Looks like this is a bug. I removed the dev tool and it works.

Comment: Thank you so much this solution needs to be more popular!!!